# Computing $g^y\bmod p$ from $g^{y^2}\bmod p$ if Diffie-Hellman is compromised?

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

Given generator $g$ of a multiplicative group mod a prime $p$ the Diffie Hellman problem is to find $$g^{xy}\bmod p$$ from $g^x\bmod p$ and $g^y\bmod p$. The best way to solve this is through discrete logarithms. Assume we can do this without breaking discrete logarithms.

Then is computing $g^z\bmod p$ from $g^{z^2}\bmod p$ doable in polynomial time?

Comment: Assume that an Oracle provide the results, then can you verify the result without knowing $z$

Answer (score 1):

> Then is computing $g^z\bmod p$ from $g^{z^2}\bmod p$ doable in polynomial time?

If we assume that we know the order $q$ of $g$, and that it is prime, then yes, it is feasible.

Then, we can treat members of this subgroup as an abstract group, where each member is $g^a$ for some $a$.  Within this abstract group, we can perform multiplication with the Oracle, that is, given $g^a$ and $g^b$, we can compute $g^{ab \bmod q}$.  By extension, we can perform exponentiation in polynomial time, that is, given $g^a$ and an integer $c$, we can compute $g^{a^c \bmod q}$.  And, we can compute the additive inverse (given $g^a$, we can compute $g^{-a \bmod q}$)

We further have an equality operator on this group, that is, given $g^a$ and $g^b$, we can determine whether $a \equiv b \pmod q$).

These operations are sufficient to implement the [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) algorithm within the abstract group; this allows us to compute square-roots in polynomial time [1], and specifically, given $g^{z^2}$, to recover the two square root elements $g^z$ and $g^{-z}$

---

[1]: Probabilistic polynomial time if $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$; however the probabilistic step is to find a quadratic nonresidue, and that needs to be done only once for a specific group.

Comment: I thought there is a cryptosystem based on difficulty of the problem?

Comment: @1..: the above analysis is assuming that we have a CDH oracle; for a group where we don't have such a CDH oracle, it would appear to be a secure hard problem...

Comment: is it possible to say in P which is positive root and which is negative root?